# Determining values when absolute changes are given

Tags: arithmetic, inverse, ratio

I took an equation Say  $p \times q = k $

When $p$ and $q$ changes by some percentages $a%, b%$ we can calculate the percentage change in $k$ as $\left( {a + b + \dfrac{{ab}}{{100}}} \right)\% $

But I am interested in finding $k$ when $p$, $q$ changes by some absolute value.

For example, when $p$ changed $+5$, then $q$ got changed by $ - \dfrac{1}{3}$ and when $p$ changed $-5$, then $q$ got changed by $\dfrac{1}{2}$ where $p \times q = k $

This is easy to solve by using equations.

$$p \times q = k$$
$$\left( {p + 5} \right) \times \left( {q - \dfrac{1}{3}} \right) = k$$
$$\left( {p - 5} \right) \times \left( {q + \dfrac{1}{2}} \right) = k$$

I got $p = 25$, $q = 2$

I observed that

$$\frac{{p + 5}}{{p - 5}} = \frac{{\left( {\frac{{\partial {p_1}}}{{\partial {q_1}}}} \right)}}{{\left( {\frac{{\partial {p_2}}}{{\partial {q_2}}}} \right)}}$$

Here $\partial {p_1},\partial {p_2},\partial {q_1},\partial {q_2}$ are absolute changes in $p, q$.

$$\frac{{p + 5}}{{p - 5}} = \frac{{\left( {\frac{5}{{1/3}}} \right)}}{{\left( {\frac{5}{{1/2}}} \right)}} = \frac{3}{2}$$

I would like to know what is the theory behind these ratios.  I used this concept for wide range of problems but don't know why the above expression holds good.  Can any one throw some light on this concept?

Comment: While the symbol $\partial$ is often used as part of the notation for a partial derivative, the notation $\partial X$ often means "the boundary of $X$". But in your case you just mean the difference of two discrete values, or maybe the absolute value of that difference. There are no PDEs in sight here.

Comment: where does the $\dfrac 12$ and $p = 25$ come from?

Comment: When $p$ is reduced by 5, $q$ increases by $\dfrac{1}{2}$.  When you solve all the three equations, you get $p = 25$

Comment: I can solve this question by using equations, but I would like to know the last part of the equation why it holds good.  Is there any theory behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set up a system of simultaneous equations that can be
solved by high-school algebra.

Let's write the equations with letters $a, b, c, d$ instead of the numbers $5$, $\frac13$, and so forth. That way we can hope to come up with formulas that will explain how these systems of equations work in general.
The equations can then be written
\begin{gather}
pq = k \\
(p+a)(q+b) = k \\
(p+c)(q+d) = k \\
\end{gather}
Here the letters $a, b, c, d$ are assumed to be constants that will
be replaced by known numeric values when you solve a particular problem.
We'll assume that $a\neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$.

The equations can be rewritten as follows by expanding the products
of the terms in parentheses:
\begin{gather}
pq = k \\
pq + bp + aq + ab = k \\
pq + dp + cq + cd = k \\
\end{gather}
Since $pq = k$, then $k - pq = 0$, so if we subtract $pq$ from each side
of the last two equations we get
\begin{gather}
bp + aq + ab = k - pq = 0\\
dp + cq + cd = k - pq = 0\\
\end{gather}
So we're down to just two equations in two unknowns.
We can multiply the first equation by $\frac1a$ and the second
by $\frac1/c$ to get
\begin{gather}
\frac ba p + q + b = 0\\
\frac dc p + q + d = 0\\
\end{gather}
Subtract the second equation from the first, and we have
$$
\frac ba p - \frac dc p + b - d = 0,
$$
therefore
$$
\left(\frac ba - \frac dc\right) p = d - b,
$$
so
$$
p = \frac{d - b }{\frac ba - \frac dc}
= \frac{d - b}{\left(\frac {bc - ad}{ac}\right)}
= \frac{acd - abc}{bc - ad}.
$$
In your example, 
$a = 5$, $b = -\frac13$, $c = -5$, and $d = \frac12$, so
\begin{align}
p &= \frac{5(-5)\frac12 - 5\left(-\frac13\right)(-5)}
{\left(-\frac13\right)(-5) - 5\left(\frac12\right)} \\
&= \frac{-5(5)\frac12 - 5\left(\frac13\right)(5)}
{\left(\frac13\right)(5) - 5\left(\frac12\right)} 
 && \text{resolving the negative signs}\\
&= \frac{-5\left(\frac12\right) - 5\left(\frac13\right)}{\frac13 - \frac12}
 && \text{canceling factors of $5$}\\
&= \frac{\left(-\frac{25}6\right)}{\left(-\frac16\right)}\\
&= 25.
\end{align}

Your formula with $\frac{p+5}{p-5}$ on the left hand side is more generally
\begin{align}
\frac{p+a}{p+c} &=
\frac{\frac{acd - abc}{bc - ad} + a}{\frac{acd - abc}{bc - ad} + c} \\
&= \frac{\left(\frac{acd - abc + a(bc - ad)}{bc - ad}\right)}
        {\left(\frac{acd - abc + c(bc - ad)}{bc - ad}\right)} \\
&= \frac{acd - a^2d}{acd - abc + bc^2 - acd} \\
&= \frac{acd - a^2d}{bc^2 - abc}\\
&= \frac{ad(c - a)}{bc(c-a)}\\
&= \frac{ad}{bc} \\
&= \frac{\left(\frac ab\right)}{\left(\frac cd\right)}.
\end{align}

Your formula is almost the same:
$$
\frac{p+a}{p+c} =
 \frac{\left(\frac{|a|}{|b|}\right)}{\left(\frac{|c|}{|d|}\right)}
$$
where $|b|$ is the absolute value of $b$, so we take $\frac13$
instead of $-\frac13$.
This works out because if $p$, $q$, and $k$ are positive
then $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs, and $c$ and $d$ have opposite
signs, so the signs end up canceling out.

Comment: I perfectly understand your solution.  But please observer the following. Let $p = 12$, $q = 20$ Therefore Product = $240$. Now increase p by 3, then q becomes 16.  Decrease p by 2, then q becomes 24.  $15 \times 16 = 240 $ also $10 \times 24 = 240$.  What I am saying is using the changes, $$\frac{{p + 3}}{{p - 2}} = \frac{{3/4}}{{2/4}} = \frac{3}{2}$$ <br> so p = 12.  I am unable to understand, from where this cute little thing is coming.

Comment: It's also proved by algebra, using the solution for $p$. I've now written up that part.

Comment: There's probably a simpler way to do it. Maybe we'll see a better answer posted.